# How to disable Vibration in Android devices?

Tags: vibration

I find vibration super annoying and utterly useless, especially in tablets.
I want to totally disable or even destroy, if needed, the vibration feature or part of all my 6 Google Nexus phones and tablets, and 1 Samsung tablet.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mobile. On Samsung Galaxy S7, there's "Sounds and Vibration" in "Settings".

For Nexus devices, you may want to check [Change volume, sound & vibrate settings.](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819577?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any clue about Nexus devices? I have only 1 Sumsung tablet, but 6 Nexus phones and tablets.

Comment: @NickChen Updated my answer for Nexus devices.

Comment: I have stock ROMs from Google on all Nexus devices, mostly rooted. There is no option to disable vibration or haptic feedback in Settings, not even the Developer options.

Comment: In AOSP there is no way to entirely disable vibration to my knowledge (currently running Android 7.1.2.).

Comment: Is their anything like sound & vibration settings, Sometimes you will have sound profiles in their, you'll see the one that you're using is marked beside it, Try to open the settings for the profile your using and then see if you can turn it off in their ... so Sound & Vibration > Profile Settings Button > Turn of vibration . ???? I'm on 5.0 so I'm not sure if it's still their

Answer (score 0):

[Install Vibration Tuner Xposed module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ztc1997.vibrationtuner) (root required) after installing [Xposed framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) and set "global vibration strength" to `0%`.

Compatible with at least Android 5-7 (I don't personally own a device with Oreo installed).